# Building an "implicit" filter with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am looking for a way to build an "implicit" filter, that does the same in dplyr as the code below using data.table.

```
library(data.table)

df_test = data.frame(Idx = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9),
                     Cond = c(T, T, F, T, T,F, F, T),
                     Val = c(T, T, F, T, T, F, T, T))

setDT(df_test)

df_test[Cond == TRUE, Res := cumsum(Val)]
```

Thanks for your help
Best Alexander

Comment: Do you mean that rolling function be applied on certain column after applying on filter in another column

Comment: `library(tidyverse)

df_test %>% filter(Cond == T) %>% mutate(res = cumsum(Val))
`

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` semantics:

```
df_test %>% mutate(Res = if_else(!Cond, NA_integer_, cumsum(if_else(Cond, as.integer(Val), 0L))))
```

Comment: This syntax does not produce results that match `data.table`. The last row in the `data.table` output has Res = 5, whereas in `dplyr` it is equal to 6. Therefore, the `cumsum()` function in dplyr isn't being applied conditionally based on the input.

Comment: hi, unfortunately the results do not match. your last value is 6, whereas it should be 5

Comment: @LenGreski Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your query:

```
> df_test = data.frame(Idx = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9),
+                      Cond = c(T, T, F, T, T,F, F, T),
+                      Val = c(T, T, F, T, T, F, T, T))
> df_test
  Idx  Cond   Val
1   1  TRUE  TRUE
2   2  TRUE  TRUE
3   3 FALSE FALSE
4   4  TRUE  TRUE
5   5  TRUE  TRUE
6   6 FALSE FALSE
7   7 FALSE  TRUE
8   9  TRUE  TRUE
> df_test %>% mutate(Res = if_else(Cond, cumsum(Cond), NA_integer_))
  Idx  Cond   Val Res
1   1  TRUE  TRUE   1
2   2  TRUE  TRUE   2
3   3 FALSE FALSE  NA
4   4  TRUE  TRUE   3
5   5  TRUE  TRUE   4
6   6 FALSE FALSE  NA
7   7 FALSE  TRUE  NA
8   9  TRUE  TRUE   5
>
```

OR

```
> df_test %>% filter(Cond == TRUE) %>% mutate(Res = cumsum(Val)) %>% right_join(df_test) %>% arrange(Idx)
Joining, by = c("Idx", "Cond", "Val")
  Idx  Cond   Val Res
1   1  TRUE  TRUE   1
2   2  TRUE  TRUE   2
3   3 FALSE FALSE  NA
4   4  TRUE  TRUE   3
5   5  TRUE  TRUE   4
6   6 FALSE FALSE  NA
7   7 FALSE  TRUE  NA
8   9  TRUE  TRUE   5
>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. You are summing up Cond. By coincidence it gives the right result. But based on Cond the Val columns should be summed when TRUE

Comment: How about my second code? I am summing using Val column.

Answer (score 0):

The question uses `data.table` to conditionally calculate a cumulative sum based on values of the `Cond` column.

The minimal example provided generates the following output:

```
> df_test[Cond == TRUE, Res := cumsum(Val)]
> df_test
   Idx  Cond   Val Res
1:   1  TRUE  TRUE   1
2:   2  TRUE  TRUE   2
3:   3 FALSE FALSE  NA
4:   4  TRUE  TRUE   3
5:   5  TRUE  TRUE   4
6:   6 FALSE FALSE  NA
7:   7 FALSE  TRUE  NA
8:   9  TRUE  TRUE   5
```

Notice that the value of `Res` in row 8 is 5.

Unfortunately, this is not easy to reproduce in `dplyr` because the `cumsum()` function doesn't work conditionally within an `if_else()` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df_test = data.frame(Idx = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9),
                     Cond = c(T, T, F, T, T,F, F, T),
                     Val = c(T, T, F, T, T, F, T, T))
                   
df_test %>% mutate(Res = if_else(Cond, cumsum(Val), NA_integer_))
```

...produces a value of 6 in row 8 of the output data frame.

```
> df_test %>% mutate(Res = if_else(Cond, cumsum(Val), NA_integer_))
  Idx  Cond   Val Res
1   1  TRUE  TRUE   1
2   2  TRUE  TRUE   2
3   3 FALSE FALSE  NA
4   4  TRUE  TRUE   3
5   5  TRUE  TRUE   4
6   6 FALSE FALSE  NA
7   7 FALSE  TRUE  NA
8   9  TRUE  TRUE   6
```

To correct this, one must filter the TRUE values from FALSE, calculate the cumulative sum only on TRUE rows, and merge the false ones back into the result.

```
df_test %>% 
     filter(Cond == TRUE) %>% 
     mutate(Res = cumsum(Val)) -> df_true 
df_test %>% filter(Cond == FALSE) %>%
     bind_rows(.,df_true) %>% arrange(Idx)
```

...and the output:

```
  Idx  Cond   Val Res
1   1  TRUE  TRUE   1
2   2  TRUE  TRUE   2
3   3 FALSE FALSE  NA
4   4  TRUE  TRUE   3
5   5  TRUE  TRUE   4
6   6 FALSE FALSE  NA
7   7 FALSE  TRUE  NA
8   9  TRUE  TRUE   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have found a solution by myself. Comments are welcome if you find any shortcomings...

```
library(dplyr)

df_test %>%
  group_by(Cond) %>%
  mutate(Res = ifelse(Cond == 1, cumsum(Val), NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```